# QuickFix in Custom Language(Xtext) using Language Server Protocol

Tags: java, server-side, client-side, xtext, language-server-protocol

I am very new to Language Server Protocol.

I have all the xtext related files ie. content assist, validation, quick fixes etc in eclipse and our client is intellij.

I want to implement quickfixes using LSP which are already present in eclipse. 
Can some one guide me?

Comment: did you checkout https://github.com/xtext/xtext-languageserver-example/blob/master/org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/MyDslIdeQuickfixProvider.java or https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/748d40a1cd0c0400ac799ab3038e6e0e8b77e9cb/org.eclipse.xtext.ide.tests/testlang-src/org/eclipse/xtext/ide/tests/testlanguage/ide/quickfix/TestLanguageQuickFixProvider.java#L11

Comment: I checked these links and found that `MyDslIdeQuickfixProvider`  is added in eclipse code and which is bind in `MyDslIdeModule` along with `QuickFixCodeActionService`.

I also did in the same way but still on error when I hover in runtime intellij, I can only see error but not quickfix even while debugging, quickfix class is not called.

Do I need anything in intellij code as well?

Comment: did you check which services intellij calls. did you also check the client/server options on the initialize calls?

Comment: does it work in vscode?

Comment: I don't have vscode. I tried to check in generated json file but couldn't find `textDocument/codeAction`

Comment: you mean requests sent from the client to the server? then maybe intellij does not send the request for unknown reason.
did you try to use the example in intellij if it works there?

Comment: I found `codeActionProvider: false` in transmitted json file.
But how to make it true because I thought this is automatically handled by Diagnostics as we are writing Diagnostics code when code is already defined if any error is available and it has `issue.getCode()` also . issue here is `org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Issue`

Comment: see org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.LanguageServerImpl.createServerCapabilities(InitializeParams)
it does
  serverCapabilities.setCodeActionProvider(allLanguages.stream()
    .anyMatch((serviceProvider) -> serviceProvider.get(ICodeActionService2.class) != null));

so i assume you miss 

https://github.com/xtext/xtext-languageserver-example/blob/771848ec2b1967dbe8464a42ec0970d0f4c0dd59/org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/MyDslIdeModule.java#L31

Comment: No, I added that already, I have bind ICodeActionService2 to QuickFixCodeActionService

Comment: can you please provide a reproducer or debug the place i mentioned?

Comment: My quickfixes are visible now and working as well. Thank you very much

Comment: But I have one more doubt, Since I already have one quickFixProvider class in .ui plugin, Can I somehow use that or call that in this MyDslQuickFIxProvider (written in .ide plugin)so that the code will not overwrite?

Comment: no, you cant. maybe you can call the one in ide from ui. but the one in the ui may use eclipse ui api so it wont work outside of eclipse

Comment: maybe you can contribute something like UiToIdeContentProposalProvider for Quickfixes to Xtext

Comment: Is there any example present somewhere for this to get some idea?

Comment: no if there was you would not have to do anything

Comment: If the dsl file name and root name in dsl is difefrent, how can I change the file name using quickfix in intellij?

Comment: i dont know if the protocol has direct support for that

Comment: maybe you can produce a RenameFile workspace edit.
but dont know if this is supported by intellij

Comment: see https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#workspaceEdit